# Probability Mutually Exclusive events

Tags: statistics

Events A and B are mutually exclusive. Suppose event A occurs with probability 0.39 and event B occurs with probability 0.32. If A does not occur, what is the probability that B does not occur?

I tried like you said (B|A¯)=P(B∩A¯)/P(A¯)=(0.32*0.61)/0.61= 0.119072=0.12 (Correct to 2 decimal places)

Is it Right?

Comment: No.  You've not made use of the fact that $A$ didn't happen.

Comment: ohhh, but how do I solve this question?

Comment: Nothing I am sorry, I am just stupid

Comment: Are you familiar with Bayes' rule? That should help you calculate $\Pr(B^c \vert A^c)$.

Comment: @MaxFt he's looking for $P(\bar{B}\vert\bar{A})$.

Comment: Draw a Venn diagram.

Comment: I tried like you said (B|A¯)=P(B∩A¯)/P(A¯)=(0.32*0.61)/0.61= 0.119072=0.12 (Correct to 2 decimal places)

Comment: Use the rule $P(U\mid V)P(V)=P(U\cap V)$ for appropriate $U$ and $V$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think all this stuff is easier by diagrams.  You're told this, thanks to $A$ and $B$ being m.e.

[image]

Since you are told (conditional prob.) that $A$ did not occur, your entire universe/denominator is out of $0.61$ instead of $1$.  Out of this universe, you need to know how $B$ fails to occur. This is just the $0.29$, NOT including the $0.39$ because you know that $A$ did NOT happen.  Hence the answer is 
$$
\frac{0.29}{0.61} \approx 0.4754.
$$
In short, draw the diagram, then take your scissors and cut out the $A$ ring.  Now proceed as usual.  All you're using is $P(C \mid D) = \frac{P(C \cap D)}{P(D)}$ by thinking in terms of the diagram.   I find this so much more intuitive than chasing formulas.

Answer (score 1):

$\mathbb P (\bar B|\bar A) = \frac{\mathbb P (\bar A \cap \bar B)}{\mathbb P (\bar A)} = \frac{\mathbb P (\overline{ A \cup B})}{\mathbb P (\bar A)} =\frac{1-\mathbb P ( A \cup B)}{1-\mathbb P (A)} = \frac{1-(\mathbb P ( A ) + \mathbb P (B))}{1-\mathbb P (A)} = 1 - \frac{\mathbb P (B)}{1-\mathbb P ( A )} = 1 - \frac{0.32}{0.61} = 0.48$

Comment: Ahah I keep writing too fast. I corrected it. Thanks